# StoreKit Error Codes

Tags: ios, objective-c, storekit

Does anyone know where I can find a list of all of StoreKit's error codes and descriptions. It was hinted at in WWDC 2014, session 303 (Optimizing In-App Purchases) but the person never provided a URL and I can't for the life me find the correct document.

I found SKError.h - but it doesn't seem to be the complete list (ie. `Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=16 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"` is not mentioned in there, nor does the enum go as high as 17 items).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this issue resolved? because I'm facing this too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem - with the message "Error Domain=SSErrorDomain Code=16 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo=0x16d91a80 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}".

But I notice the error identifier is not SKErrorDomain, as defined in SKError.h, it's *SSErrorDomain*.  I think the "SS" stands for sockets stream, so this is some much lower level connectivity error in the networking frameworks.

Did you figure out what was wrong?

Comment: No sweat, I'm working on it full time, I'll let you know if I find anything.

Comment: sadly no :( once I do/if I do, I'll make sure to post it.

Comment: I concluded the issue was not connected to a particular problem in my code - but I couldn't attribute it to a definite external cause.  But when I made sure that 1) the device had a good network connection (e.g. no Wifi issues) and 2) I entered the correct credentials for the iTunes test account, the problem didn't come up again for me.  Which is consistent with my suspicion that it was a connectivity problem at the sockets level.

Sorry if that's not very helpful to you, but the issue proved not to be a continuing problem for me.  Typical of IAP, a quirky one-off with no clear cause or fix.